# Matlab script operator overloading

Tags: matlab

I was wondering if it is possible to replace this:

```
function y = par(Z1,Z2)
y=1./(1./Z1+1./Z2);
return;
```

with some sort of "operator overloading" as in the language C++. So lets say it would become possible to call the function "Z1#Z2" instead of "par(Z1,Z2)"

Comment: Yes, but `Z1` and `Z2` would need to be of a custom class, obviously (as in good-practice C++). Start reading about MATLAB's OOP capabilities [here](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/object-oriented-programming.html). The question you should ask yourself is: is replacing this one function by some nicer syntax really worth the trouble of writing the class?

Comment: I would also re-write that as `Z1.*Z2./(Z1+Z2)`

Comment: Even using a custom class would not work because `#` would need to be a valid and overloadable operator in matlab, which it is not. The same is true for C++ though I'm not entirely sure of that.

Comment: @Tobold: Nope, [`#` is not a C++ operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B), let alone an overloadable one :)

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis: That C++ doesn't allow it is cristal clear to me. Though it would be nice to know definetly wheter the rule applies also to matlab

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an example:

```
classdef myClass < double

    methods

        %// constructor
        function this = myClass(varargin)
            this = this@double(varargin{:});
        end

        %// Special syntax for harmonic mean
        function new = mldivide(this, other)
            new = this.*other./(this + other);
        end

    end

end
```

Usage:

```
>> Z1 = myClass(rand(4));
>> Z2 = myClass(rand(4));
>> Z3 = Z1 \ Z2;              %// calls your harmonic mean function
```

Answer (score 1):

MATLAB does support operator overloading, but not in the way that you're envisioning.  Operator overloading can only be performed on your own custom classes that you create in MATLAB.

Check out http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/implementing-operators-for-your-class.html.  If you seriously want to do operator overloading, you will need to learn about MATLAB's Object Oriented Programming paradigm first.

Check this link out:  http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/object-oriented-programming.html